# Почему при вызове метода класса его элементы имеют свойство undefined? JS

Tags: javascript

столкнулся с тем что при вызове метода консоль выдает ошибку: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined

объект создан через new, метод вызван через eventListener

полный код класса: https://jsfiddle.net/Genry__12_Oz/owak6j98/2/

```
closeForms() {
        // обнуляю кнопку submit
        this.popUpButton.classList.remove('popup__button_content'); // почему popUpButton undefined?      
        this.popUpButton.classList.remove('popup__button_edit'); // дольше во всех this. такая же ошибка
        this.popUpButton.classList.remove('popup__button_valid');
        // обнуляю ошибки валидации
        nameError.textContent = '';
        aboutError.textContent = '';
        // обнуляю условие
        this.inputName.removeAttribute('minlength');             
        this.inputName.removeAttribute('maxlength');              
        // здесь тоже
        this.inputAbout.removeAttribute('minlength');              
        this.inputAbout.removeAttribute('maxlength');
        // обнуляю тип
        this.inputAbout.removeAttribute('type');                 
        // обнуляю name
        this.form.removeAttribute('name');
    }
```

Comment: А чему равен this при вызове функции?

Comment: я вешаю слушатель на кнопку закрытия в этом же классе 

`setEventListener() {
        this.closeButton
        .addEventListener('click', this.closeForms);
    }`

вызывается по клику ссылаться должен на этот объект по сути

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...addEventListener('click', this.closeForms.bind(this));
```

Comment: Igor, спасибо большое) помогло

единственное не пойму, если нужна жесткая привязка, значит значение элемента как то перезаписывается, вот только почему и где?